# ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 Controllers to View data access

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET and learning as I go by doing some personal projects.

So my question is how to access data that is passed from controller to the view?

Here is my controller code:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(PowerShellCmd script)
        {
            PowerShellModule execute = new PowerShellModule();
            var results = execute.ExecuteCode(script);
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var psObject in results)
            {
                // Convert the Base Object to a string and append it to the string builder.
                // Add \r\n for line breaks
                builder.AppendLine(psObject.BaseObject.ToString());
            }
            var data = builder.ToString();
            return View(data); // Transfer data to view
        }
```

In the return view above I am providing a variable that I want to access in the view. So in view I used below code with `@Model` to access the data in front end. I am not sure if that is the right way, but any suggestion is appreciated. :)

```
<textarea asp-for="CmdOutput" style="width:700px; height:200px;">
    @Model
</textarea>
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20333225/2030565) should answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Model**

```
    public class MyModel
    {
        public string Data { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(PowerShellCmd script)
    {
        PowerShellModule execute = new PowerShellModule();
        var results = execute.ExecuteCode(script);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var psObject in results)
        {
            // Convert the Base Object to a string and append it to the string builder.
            // Add \r\n for line breaks
            builder.AppendLine(psObject.BaseObject.ToString());
        }
        MyModel myModel = new MyModel();
        myModel.Data = builder.ToString();
        return View(myModel); // Transfer data to view
    }
```

**View**

```
@model MyModel

<div>
@MyModel.Data
</div>
```