# ASP.NET MVC5 Invalid ModelState: How to pass foreign key to drop-down and pass it back on HTTPPost?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I've a Project model like below:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ....

    [Required]
    public virtual ApplicationUser Client { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Client")]
    public string ClientID;


    [Required]
    public virtual ApplicationUser ProjectManager { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("ProjectManager")]
    public string ProjectManagerID;

    ....


}
```

In tried to pass users with specified role inside create action like below,using ViewBag:

```
// GET: /Project/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    populateRoles();
    SelectList PMs = new SelectList(projectManagers, "Id", "Name");
    ViewBag.ProjectManagerID = PMs;
    SelectList Clients = new SelectList(clients, "Id", "Name");
    ViewBag.ClientID = Clients;
    return View();
}
```

And here is the part of Razor View for drop-downs:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Project Manager", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("ProjectManagerID", ViewBag.ProjectManagerID as SelectList, new { @class = "col-md-10 control-label" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Client", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("ClientID", ViewBag.ClientID as SelectList, new { @class = "col-md-10 control-label" })
    </div>
</div>
```

There is no problem up to here, but on form post my model will not have valid state:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Progress,CreateDate")] Project project)
{
    /*---------------------populate select lists ------*/
    populateRoles();
    SelectList PMs = new SelectList(projectManagers, "Id", "Name");
    ViewBag.ProjectManagerID = PMs;
    SelectList Clients = new SelectList(clients, "Id", "Name");
    ViewBag.ClientID = Clients;
    /*-----------try to fix invalid modelstate ---------*/
    string projectManagerID = Request["PMs"];
    string clientID = Request["Clients"];
    project.ProjectManagerID = projectManagerID;
    project.ClientID = clientID;

    if (ModelState.IsValid) // <-Invalid modelstate because required foreign key properties
    {
        dbContext.Projects.Add(project);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(project);
}
```

The Question: How to pass required foreign key properties here?

Comment: What exactly are your model state errors?

Comment: @Moby'sStuntDouble error is on [required] property of foreign key items and both of properties  `Client` and `ProjectManager` are null in `ModelState`.

Comment: Use a view model instead of your entity model to transfer data from view to controller.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333021/asp-net-mvc-how-to-pass-data-from-view-to-controller/20333225#20333225

Comment: @Shyju handling ViewModels itself have some overheads. Are there any other straight way to handle my propblem?

Comment: The clean solution is to NOT USE the entities generated by your ORM in your UI layer (that is tight coupling). Use a view model so that anytime you want to switch your db access layer to something else,you don't need to touch your UI layer.

Comment: @Shyju So, how should I select Client and ProjectManager of my Project in the UI?

Comment: you need to create  a view model with the properties needed for your view.SO has a lot of samples. Start with the link i posted earlier.

Comment: You cannot use the same name for the `ViewBag` `SelectList` and and the property your binding to. Use a view model. And you cannot apply a [Required]` attribute to a complex property. And you excluding you property from binding because of your `[Bind]` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you are using the framework in the correct fashion in your controller. Using Request items is leaving behind all of the things that the ASP.NET MVC framework is trying to do for you. It should really read along the following lines:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(string submitButton)
    {
        var model = new MyClass();  // go and get the record you want to edit
        if (submitButton == "Save")
        {
            TryUpdateModel(model);
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) // if the modelstate isn't valid, setup the dropdowns for the return trip to the form
            {
                ViewData["OrganizationId"] = model.OrganizationId;
                ViewBag.RecordTypes = GetRecordTypes(model.OrganizationId);
                return View(model);
            }
            context.AddToMyType(model);
            context.SaveChanges(); // save changes if there are no errors
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = model.OrganizationId });
    }
```

The reality is that you should be allowing ASP.NET MVC to handle almost all of your binding. It's only in very particular circumstances that you should override it.

As an additional point, as Shyju also says in the comments, best practice dictates that you should also use a dedicated view model for this rather than your domain model.

P.S. Lecturing aside (sorry), the specific reason why your code is non-operational is that the ProjectManager property is not set at the time you are calling SaveChanges(). You have only set ProjectManagerID, this will not automagically set the ProjectManager property for you, you have to do that yourself if you don't use the bindings as intended in MVC.

Good luck with your app!

Comment: `var model = GetRecord(id);`  is not going to work, since I'm going to create an instance which is not existing yet.

Comment: Meanwhile there are not methods to set `ProjectManager` inside View?

Comment: Sure, so on create, the process is the same, just without that call. I'll update the answer for a Create post

Comment: RE: ProjectManager property honestly, it simply depends on how you name your properties and whether you deploy the object property or the foreign key property to the form. Too long to get into here, but you may need to look up the object by ID and set ProjectManager and the other object property manually before SaveChanges() based on how you have things currently.