# How to pass data from different controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewbag, tempdata

I am trying to pass a value which is stored in one controller to another, code is below:

**Charities Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Donate([Bind(Include = "ID,DisplayName,Date,Amount,Comment")] Charity charity)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(charity.Comment))
            {
                var comment = charity.Comment.ToLower().Replace("hot", "###").Replace("cold", "###").Replace("Slow", "###").Replace("enjoy", "###").Replace("BAD", "###");
                charity.Comment = comment;  //Replaces textx from model variable - comment

                charity.TaxBonus = 0.20 * charity.Amount;


            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(charity.DisplayName))
            {
                charity.DisplayName = "Annonymus"; //If user doesnt enter name then Annonymus

            }
             db.Donations.Add(charity);
            db.SaveChanges();
            TempData["Name"] = charity.DisplayName;
            TempData["Amount"] = charity.Amount;
            TempData["Comment"] = charity.Comment;
            return RedirectToAction("../Payments/Payment", "Charities", new { id = charity.Amount });
        }
        return View(charity);
    }
```

**Charities Class**

```
 public class Charity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use letters only please")]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Range(2, Int32.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Atleast £2.00 or a whole number please")]
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public Double TaxBonus { get; set; }
    public String Comment { get; set; }
    public static object Information { get; internal set; }
}
```

**Payment Controller**

```
      [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Payment([Bind(Include = "ID,CardName,CardNumber,ValidFrom,Expires,CardSecurityCode,EmailAddress,ConfrimEmailAddress,Address,City,Country,PostCode")] Payment payment)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Payments.Add(payment);
            db.SaveChanges();
            TempData["Name"] = charity.DisplayName
            TempData["Amount"];
             TempData["Comment"];
            TempData["Name"] = payment.CardName;
            TempData["Email"] = payment.EmailAddress;
            return RedirectToAction("Confirmation", "Payments", new { id = payment.ID });
        }

        return View(payment);

    }
```

**Payment Class**

```
public class Payment
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
 }
public class CharityDBContext : DbContext //controls information in database 
{
    public DbSet<Charity> Donations { get; set; } //creates a donation database

}

public class PaymentDBContext : DbContext //controls information in database 
{
    public DbSet<Payment> Payments { get; set; } //creates a donation database

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<CharitySite.Models.Charity> Charities { get; set; }
}
```

}

**I am trying to get this from the Charities Controller**

```
TempData["Name"] = charity.DisplayName;
```

**To display in Payment controller**

```
 TempData["Name"] = charity.DisplayName;
```

Right now theres a squigly red line under "charity" in the payment controller with the message - doesnt exist in current context. I just wanted to know if it is possible to pass data from different controllers using temp data.

Comment: Nothing makes sense with your code. First of all you have not even shown the GET method for `Payment` that you redirecting to. And the error is because there is no variable named `charity` in the POST method.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the line `return RedirectToAction` in your Donate method is going to send a 302 response to your browser which will  issue a GET request to the url in the location header of the response, which in this case is `Payment/Payment`. But your Payment method is marked with HttpPost.  Are you sure you want to send a second  GET request to a method marked with HttpPost to save  some part of the data(`Payment`) you want to save ?

I think you should save your charity and payment info in the same action method( *Create a PaymentCharity view model and use that instead of using the Bind attribute and the entity classes created by EF to [transfer data from your view to action method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333021/asp-net-mvc-how-to-pass-data-from-view-to-controller/20333225#20333225)*). Also, insteaof using TempData to pass data, What you should do is, get the unique id of the Payment record you saved, pass that in  querystring  to the second action method and in that using the unique payment id,read the payment record again and use that.

So in your Donate method,

```
public ActionResult Donate(PaymentCharirtVm model)
{
   var charity = new Charity { DisplayName =model.Amount,Comment =model.Comment};
   var payment = new Payment ();
   //set the properties of payment here

   db.Donations.Add(charity);
   db.SaveChanges();
   //now save Payment
   db.Payment.Add(payment);
   db.SaveChanges();
   return RedirectToAction("Confirmation","Payment", new { id=payment.Id });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried to do it with tempdata. Have never needed to. I recomend you add the string with the charity name to the view model used by the payment controller.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct code as below to retrieve value from TempData.

```
charity.DisplayName= TempData["Name"]
```

Answer (score 0):

As already answered here, most answer are correct. It would be better to use routeValues in the RedirectToAction method to pass value from one action to another action in the same controller or different controller.

```
        return RedirectToAction("actionName", "anotherControllerName", new { id = charity.DisplayName });
```

In the another controller, data can be retrieved by

```
        string displayName = RouteData.Values["id"].ToString();
```

Here, in the routeValues, you can pass the whole Charity object as well and do some casting in the another controller to get the object properly in the that case when you need more than one properties to be sent:

```
        return RedirectToAction("actionName", "anotherControllerName", new { id = charity });
```

And get it by:

```
        Charity chatiry = (Charity)RouteData.Values["id"];
```

I hope that you will get some idea from this.