# How to pass value to view from controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Am a new to MVC.And am using MVC4. Am developing simple login application. Once the login success, i will get the values from the user in two textbox. If i click submit button in that page, i entered textbox value will be displayed in another page. Am facing issue on displaying the textbox value in display page.

I would like to show the controller object value in view page(Display). i could not display the data.

Model:

```
 public class DisplayModel
    {
        public string setupName { get; set; }
        public string displayName { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Display(DisplayModel setupDetails)
        {
            ViewData["setupDetails"] = setupDetails;

            return View(setupDetails);
        }
```

View:

```
@model SampleApplicationWithLoginValidation.Models.DisplayModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Display";
}

<h2>Display</h2>
<table border="1" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Setup Name</th>
        <th>Display Name</th>
</tr>
    <tr><td><%:((DisplayModel)Model).setupName%></td><td>Model.displayName</td></tr>

</table>
```

Can anyone please help on this?

Comment: Can you post code where you call Display method?

Comment: Unclear what your asking . You code in the POST method is returning the view, not redirecting to a `Display` page. And you use of `ViewData["setupDetails"] = setupDetails;` is pointless. And `((DisplayModel)Model).setupName` is the same as `Model.setupDetails` so its unclear why your doing that

Comment: Please review this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333021/asp-net-mvc-how-to-pass-data-from-view-to-controller

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Display(DisplayModel setupDetails)
        {
            // ViewData["setupDetails"] = setupDetails; it's not necessary, because you pass the model object to view

            return View(setupDetails);
        }
```

and

```
</tr>
    <tr><td>@Model.setupName</td><td>@Model.displayName</td></tr>    
</table>
```

I think you use razor.

B