# ASP.NET MVC: Post data from view to controller using model vs post data using angular js

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Which is the best way to post data from view to controller or post data using $http service(angular js) in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should clear your concepts from [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/call-web-api-through-angularjs/)

Comment: In the above link posting data using angular js.But is it the best way compared with this ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333021/asp-net-mvc-how-to-pass-data-from-view-to-controller)) @Singh

Comment: I think you should require simplest way to post data from view to controller using angular js

Comment: By using angularjs we have to assign $scope variables to objects manually to post data but in this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333021/asp-net-mvc-how-to-pass-data-from-view-to-controller) it automatically posted

Comment: This link have not used angular js. It is used mvc with c#.

Comment: Actually, my question is which is the best way to  post data               1.using angular js. [Example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/call-web-api-through-angularjs/)                                                                                                                                                  2.post data from strongly typed view to controller.[Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333021/asp-net-mvc-how-to-pass-data-from-view-to-controller)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the angular js code I think you want:

```
click: function () 
{
    if ($scope.myform.$valid) {
        var empdetails = 
        {
            firstname: $scope.firstnamemodel,
            lastname: $scope.lastnamemodel,
            gender: $scope.gendermodel,
            emailid: $scope.emailidmodel,
            empid: Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1), 
            isfulltime: false,
        };
        //postservice.postdata(empdetails);
        $http.post('/Registration/DoRegister', empdetails);
        $(this).dialog("close");
        $("body").css("background-color", "white");
    }
```

And this the model class of the MVC:

```
public class EmpDetails
{
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string emailid { get; set; }
    public string empid { get; set; }
    public bool isfulltime { get; set; }
}
```

But remember your model class variable name same as the angular js variable name
...And Here is my controller cal:

```
public ActionResult DoRegister(EmpDetails empdetails)
{
    //some code...
}
```

After that bt output window print option, you can check that data is posting or not.

Hope this will help...