# Is it bad practice to catch form's data in controller with FormCollection or Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view with multiple forms which does not return object models, it returns individual values that are inserted in multiple models, so could you tell me whether is it good practice to use FormCollection or Request to catch form values in this case?.

Here is I'm doing.

```
public ActionResult TraspasarMaterial(FormCollection form)
    {
        if (form == null){
            TempData["traspaso"] = false;
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        //CoboBox id_almacen_origen regresa el id_cantidad_diponible lo buscamos para sacar el id_almacen
        almacenes_materiales alm_or = db.almacenes_materiales.Find(Convert.ToInt32(form["id_almacen_origen"]));
        int id_material = Convert.ToInt32(form["id_material"]), id_almacen_origen = Convert.ToInt32(alm_or.id_almacen), id_almacen_destino = Convert.ToInt32(form["id_almacen_destino"]);
        double cantidad = Convert.ToDouble(form["cantidad"]);

        try
        {
            var cantidad_disp = (from aux in db.almacenes_materiales where aux.id_almacen == id_almacen_origen && aux.id_material == id_material select aux.existencia_material).Single();

            if (cantidad_disp >= cantidad)
            {
                almacen_produccion ap = ap_s.TraspasoMaterial(id_material, cantidad, id_almacen_destino, id_almacen_origen);
                ap_s.InsertKardex(id_material, getEmpSession(), cantidad, DateTime.Now, "Traspaso de material entre almacenes", "Traspaso de material", 0);
                var id_k = (from kardex in db.kardex_almacen select kardex.id_kardex).Max();
                ka_s.addKardexDetail(id_k, id_almacen_origen, id_almacen_destino, cantidad);

                TempData["traspaso"] = true;
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            TempData["no_material"] = true;
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }


        TempData["traspaso"] = false;
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
```

Comment: Try using a view model and you will start loving ModelBinding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333021/asp-net-mvc-how-to-pass-data-from-view-to-controller

Comment: Thank you, i didn't know it was possible to catch view models in a post action

Answer (score 0):

No, not necessarily, if form data is needed you can use the FormCollection, though typically, it is better to actually pass the values through a submit form on the page. Though there are various ways of retrieving data from a form on the page. FormCollection is a library, and using a Form with POST method is however sufficient enough with MVC; validate this request and retrieving the data from the Form can be more easily handled on the client. Using a Form is more explicit and you can see what items are being sent to the controller by requests.

For more information visit the following link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711(v=vs.100).aspx