# Passing a user-typed input from View to Action Controller via combined action link and input in ASP.Net MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

This is an `ASP.Net MVC 5` project.

I have read the following useful post:

[ASP.Net MVC How to pass data from view to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333021/asp-net-mvc-how-to-pass-data-from-view-to-controller)

Which explains how to pass data from `View` to `Controller` in `ASP.Net MVC`. The main ideas in the post are either

1. using matching-model form-post (inputs) in the `View` and name-convention-parameters in `Action Controller`, or
2. make an action-link where we have an anonymous object having name-convention-parameters as `route values` match with the parameters in the `Action Controller`.

Now I have a slightly different case here... and would like to get some ideas for work-around.

Similar to method (2) above, I already have an action-link with anonymous object having name-convention parameters generated dynamically using razor like the following:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Detail", item.DetailsName, item.ControllerName,
  new {
    pid = item.Pid, eid = item.Eid, mid = item.Mid, cid = item.Cid,
    manNo = item.TypeItem == "Create" ? item.ManCreateNo : item.ManEditNo,
    caneNo = item.TypeItem == "Create" ? item.CaneCreateNo : item.CaneEditNo,
    command = userCanAccept ? "acc" : "pass", from = ViewBag.From
  }, null)
```

And (one of the possible) corresponding `Action Controller` called by the `ActionLink` looks like the following:

```
public ActionResult DetailsChange(int pid, int eid, int mid, int cid, int manNo = 1, int caneNo = 1, string command = null, string from = null, string comment = null)
```

Now, as you can see, the `Action Link`'s parameters in the `View` and the `Action Controller`'s parameters in the `Controller` match perfectly, *except* for one: the `comment`.

All the other parameters can be rendered by the `View` by razor at rendering time, but the `comment` is supposed to be a user-typed input (text).

Now, how do I pass this `comment` from the `View` to the `Controller`, together with the rests of the parameters, when the `Action Link` is pressed? Is there work around for this in `ASP.Net MVC 5`?

Comment: And why can't you pass the `comment` in the ActionLink's anonymous object parameter ??

Comment: You need to give a bit more info on your scenario. You method suggests you changing/updating data which mean it should be a POST, not a GET. And the fact you are referring to `item` in the view suggest your generating this in a loop which will create further problems. And why are you posting back all those extra parameters instead of just the items ID and the comments?

Comment: @Fourat because the comment is not known at rendering time. The comment is known after the user type it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I need all those extra parameters in the action. Suppose we cannot put that in the link, I would like to know if there is a way to pass the comment parameter together with others.

Comment: You should not need all those parameters (your controller sent them to the view and your just sending them all back again unchanged - you would be better off just sending back the objects ID along with the comment and then get those other values again in the controller)

Comment: @StephenMuecke no, it is not like that... the action link in the View is not from the same controller. The action link in the View is generated from different controller. It makes use of the already available view (in different controller) to generate what it wants.

Comment: But its not clear why your using a link to do this. Brian Main's answer shows you one option, but since your editing data your should be using a POST, not a GET. There are multiple reasons why using a link will fail and is bad practice. The comment could be long and you will exceed the query string limit and throw an exception. You get no validation. The url is added to the users browser history and they may click it again, firing the code in the controller again etc.

Comment: Its also appears you have a loop and are generating multiple links?

Comment: @StephenMuecke ah yes, the I am in the loop and generating multiple links. And yes, the validation is not by MVC auto-validation, but by validation in the action controller itself. Also, this page is not for the normal user, but for the admin user to ease their jobs in looking at details of various items. That's why you have various "ids" for a rather complex item

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123627/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-ian).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you would use a form and post this data back, not use an ActionLink.  But, since the ActionLink is basically an `<a>` with the HREF set to the action method URL, you can append it using javascript (in HTML attributes, if you give an ID of CmtLink, for example):

```
$("#CmtLink").on("click", function() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    //I assume it doesn't exist, but it's good to check for an existing comment parameter
    //also assume at least one parameter present
    //Also assume comment control is textbox, not textarea
    href += "&comment=" + $("#comment").val();

    $("#CmtLink").attr("href", href);
});
```

On click, this can then always grab the most recent value entered, or could cancel the default behavior if comments are empty.

Comment: This is a really interesting trick! let me try that! You got my upvote anyway!. :)