# asp.net mvc redirecttoaction does not shows another page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, ext.net, redirecttoaction

I am writing a simple MVC application in which I use a form to put some data, and after I submit the form, if a particular condition is `false` I would like to show the form again, otherwise I would show another page. 
When the condition is false, I do `ReturnToAction("Form");` and it works perfectly, but, when the condition is true and I do `RedirectToAction("MyPage");` I still see the form, even if the action related to the form submission has been executed.
What am I missing? Thank you
This is my controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private static bool condition = false;

    public ActionResult Form()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CheckCondition(FormCollection form)
    {

        string username = form["txtUsername"];

        condidion = true;            

        return RedirectToAction("MyPage");
    }

    public ActionResult MyPage()
    {

        if (!condition)
        {

            return RedirectToAction("Form");
        }
        else 
        {

            return RedirectToAction("MyPage");

        }

    }
```

Here you are my Form.aspx:

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Form</title>        
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server" method="post">
     <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />

   <ext:Viewport runat="server" Layout="CenterLayout"> 
       <Items>
    <ext:FormPanel runat="server" id="Form" Url="/Home/CheckCondition"
        Width="500"
        Height="500"
        Layout="CenterLayout"
        >
        
        <Items>                   
            <ext:Window ID="Window1"
                        runat="server"
                        Closable="false"
                        Resizable="false"
                        Height="200"
                        Icon="Lock"
                        Title="Dashboard Login"
                        Draggable="false"
                        Width="350"
                        Modal="true"
                        BodyPadding="5"                                               
                        Layout="FormLayout"                        
                >
                <Items>
                    <ext:TextField ID="txtUsername"
                                   runat="server"
                                   FieldLabel="Username"
                                   AllowBlank="false"
                                   BlankText="Your username is required."
                                   Text="Demo" />
                    <ext:TextField ID="txtPassword"
                                   runat="server"
                                   InputType="Password"
                                   FieldLabel="Password"
                                   AllowBlank="false"
                                   BlankText="Your password is required."
                                   Text="Demo" />
                </Items>
                <Buttons>
                    <ext:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" Icon="Accept">
                        <Listeners>
                            <Click Handler="
                                   if (!#{txtUsername}.validate() || !#{txtPassword}.validate()) {
                                   Ext.Msg.alert('Error','The Username and Password fields are both required');
                                // return false to prevent the btnLogin_Click Ajax Click event from firing.
                            return false;
                            } else {
                            #{Form}.submit();
                            }" />
                        </Listeners>                        
                    </ext:Button>                    
                </Buttons>
            </ext:Window>
            </Items>
</ext:FormPanel>
           </Items>
  </ext:Viewport>      
  </form>  
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you put your block of code, its hard to visualize whats going on?

Comment: should be return RedirectToAction

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the same form, you should not return a `RedirectResult`. you should call the `View` method. Also you should do the condition checking inside the http post action method which handles the form submission.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CheckCondition(FormCollection form)
{
    if (someConditionCodeGoesHere==false)  // replace this with your condition code
    {
        return View();
    }
    else 
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Success");
    }
}
public ActionResult Success()
{
   return View();
}
```

replace `someConditionCodeGoesHere` with your C# code for your condition expression. Try to embrace Stateless Http. Static variables to keep state between http call's are not a great idea.

Also consider using a view model to transfer data between your view and action method. Take a look at  [ASP.Net MVC How to pass data from view to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333021/asp-net-mvc-how-to-pass-data-from-view-to-controller/20333225#20333225)

Comment: Hi @Shyju, I have tried to do as you said and I have placed some breakpoints inside the method `CheckConditions()`. The breakpoints have been hit correctly, but when `return RedirectToAction("Success");` is reached, in the browser I still see Form instead of Success page.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem. There was an error in form submission, which went always in on failure... I resolved this problem and `RedirectToAction` worked.