# AJAX function not works (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have AJAX function in my View to pass data to Controller

Here is code of script

```
 stop.onclick = function () {
    record.disabled = false;
    stop.disabled = true;
    window.onbeforeunload = null; //Solve trouble with deleting video
    preview.src = '';

    fileName = Math.round(Math.random() * 99999999) + 99999999;
    console.log(fileName);
    var full_url = document.URL; // Get current url
    var url_array = full_url.split('/') // Split the string into an array with / as separator
    var id = url_array[url_array.length - 1];  // Get the last part of the array (-1)
    function save() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'Post',
            dataType: 'Json',
            data: {
                link: fileName.val(),
                id: id.val(),
            },
            url: '@Url.Action("LinkWriter", "Interwier")',
            success: function (da) {
                if (da.Result === "Success") {

                    alert("lol");

                } else {

                    alert('Error' + da.Message);
                }
            },
            error: function (da) {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
    }
```

Not works this part of code

```
 function save() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'Post',
            dataType: 'Json',
            data: {
                link: fileName.val(),
                id: id.val(),
            },
            url: '@Url.Action("LinkWriter", "Interwier")',
            success: function (da) {
                if (da.Result === "Success") {

                    alert("lol");

                } else {

                    alert('Error' + da.Message);
                }
            },
            error: function (da) {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is code in Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LinkWriter(string link, int id) {

        Link link_ = new Link
        {
            Link1 = link,
            Interwier_Id = id,

        };

        db.Link.Add(link_);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(new { Result = "Success", Message = "Saved Successfully" });
    }
```

I don't understand why it not works

I think I doing all right

Can you help me?

Comment: Why do you have the ajax within another function? Where are you calling the save()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `val()` as long as you got numbers in your variables:

```
data: {
   link: fileName,
   id: id,
},
```

Comment: Thank's that helps!

Answer (score 0):

try to catch value in controller using _POST :

```
Link1 = _POST['link'];
Interwier_Id = _POST['id'];
```

also remove the controller's function params :

```
public ActionResult LinkWriter() {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. It's more readable:

```
 function save() {
     $.post("@Url.Action("LinkWriter", "Interwier")", 
      { 
       link: fileName.val(),  
       id: id.val()
      })
      .done(function () {
         alert("lol");
      })
     .fail(function () {
         alert("error");
     });
}
```

Note: Check that this `fileName.val()` is **string** and this `id.val()` is **int** .
Check also that your controller name is correctly written: **InterwierController**

UPDATE:
You can do it also with ViewModels. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333021/asp-net-mvc-how-to-pass-data-from-view-to-controller).