# How to bring value of selected radio button to server side

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, variables

After getting the value, how can I bring the var to ASP.net server side so I can use it in server side?

```
function btnSelect_OnClick() {     
        var PCType;
        if (document.getElementById('r1').checked) {
            PCType = document.getElementById('r1').value);            
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) or [this AJAX resource from youmightnotneedjquery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#post)

Comment: I second AJAX. If you're using MVC you could also take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20333225/6442320).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use an AJAX solution, consider storing the value in a `HiddenField`.

**JavaScript**

```
function btnSelect_OnClick() {     
    var PCType = "";
    if (document.getElementById('r1').checked) {
        PCType = document.getElementById('r1').value);        
    }

    document.getElementById('hfPCType').value = PCType;
}
```

**ASP.Net**

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" id="hfPCType" ClientIDMode="static" />
```

**C#**

```
string PCType = hfPCType.Value;
```