# ASP.NET: How can I pass the value of a variable from a view to another one

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to pass a variable from a view to another one

so in view1 I wrote

```
@{
    var a1 = "Sample"
 }
```

in View2 I need to use the value of `a1`, so I have to write in View2

```
@{
    var a2 = a1 (a1 value is coming from View1)
 }
```

Comment: Are you using traditional form posting to controllers?

Comment: You can use session or tempdata to achieve this @HTMLMan

Comment: Well I need to pass it from a view to another, if can be done by a controller  please answer the question

Comment: @Abi please add a answer

Comment: You can use `ViewBag` or`Session`. If you need the value to be just between some specific 2 views, post to controllers.

Comment: Ho do you transition between those two action methods? If it is using a simple link or a form post you should add this as a route parameter. Else you have also the possibility to use `TempData` inside your controller

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333021/asp-net-mvc-how-to-pass-data-from-view-to-controller

Comment: Why do you want to do that: is this value entered by the end user? If not, where is the value coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using tempdata in your Controller you can achieve this..

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult TempEmp(string name)
{

                TempData["EmpName"] = name;
                return RedirectToAction("PermanentEmp");
}

 //Controller Action 2(PermanentEmployee)
 public ActionResult PermanentEmp()
{
               string empName = TempData["EmpName"] as string;
               return View(empName);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need to pass the values between views. So it has to pass between several views

Comment: You should go for session then.

Comment: Anyway, thanks a lot your solution is perfect. If you can add how to use a session would be great

Comment: Directly you can assign value to session and retrieve it wherever required.. e.g. `Session["key"] = "Value";` in view-1 and `var v = Session["key"];` in view-2