# How can i get the values of product tags created using javascript in span and pass the values to controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

[image]

```
    <input type="text" class="product-input js-product-tags" placeholder="Computer, devices, smartphone" />


    <ul class="js-tags">
     <li class="tag-options">
      <span>CPU</span><div class="remove-tag js-remove-tag">X</div>
     </li>
    </ul>
```

This is how my html tag code looks like. Please help me how can i pass these span values to controller and save in database without jquery Ajax?

Comment: Seems you are using some jQuery plugin, share that code

Comment: Have a look at this SO post on how to pass data from your view to your controller: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333021/asp-net-mvc-how-to-pass-data-from-view-to-controller

Comment: No i am not using any jquery plugin just use jquery for creating product tags on input enter event.

Comment: I don't know how to pass span values to controller and then add to c# list.

Comment: Add a name to your input?

Comment: "without jquery Ajax" meaning you want a postback?

Comment: Yes thanks for guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a postback, create hidden `input` elements:

```
<input type="text" class="product-input js-product-tags" placeholder="Computer, devices, smartphone" />
<input type="hidden" name="tags" value="CPU" />
<input type="hidden" name="tags" value="RAM" />
<input type="hidden" name="tags" value="HARDWARE" />

<ul class="js-tags">
 <li class="tag-options">
  <span>CPU</span><div class="remove-tag js-remove-tag">X</div>
  <span>RAM</span><div class="remove-tag js-remove-tag">X</div>
  <span>HARDWARE</span><div class="remove-tag js-remove-tag">X</div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

...where `tags` in `name="tags"` is your parameter name:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ICollection<string> tags) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Its working with input type hidden. Can you tell me what is the better way to do it? Is jquery ajax is better to do this sort of thing?

Comment: It depends on your application flow. If your postback page is going to load the same page, then ajax is good for a smooth experience since it is faster - less data is sent and the page is not re-rendered. In exchange, you have to handle the view in JavaScript, which leads to 2 points of maintenance when you want to change how a view looks like.