# Get Data from HTML Form to MVC Controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a nice HTML form that I want to use in a ASP.NET MVC application.

I created a method in controller to get the data via Formcollection and put it into database.

So far so good.

All the tutorials I see work the other way round, i.e. they create the form from the controller.

But I want to get data from html form. How can it be done?

Say I have this form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Form Name</legend>

<!-- Multiple Radios -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="radios">Multiple Radios</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="radio">
    <label for="radios-0">
      <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radios-0" value="1" checked="checked">
      Option one
    </label>
    </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label for="radios-1">
      <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radios-1" value="2">
      Option two
    </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Textarea -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textarea">Text Area</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">                     
    <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea" name="textarea">default text</textarea>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

I want to take the data entered by the user (I want to modify the form such that I can access it from the controller) and put it into database, how can it be accomplished by first passing the data into the controller method?

Comment: what you mean `from html form`? Is there any other forms?

Comment: set to the form action attribute value to an action method in your controller and you can read the submitted values there. Read about model binding

Comment: @Shyju any simple code example?

Comment: See the duplicate [ASP.Net MVC How to pass data from view to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333021/asp-net-mvc-how-to-pass-data-from-view-to-controller)

Answer (score 2):

should not you have an 'action' which link to your controller first?

then use Request.Form["element_name"] to get the value.

You may refer to [this site](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/understand-formcollection-in-mvc-controller/).

Comment: Although I upvoted...I wasn't asking this.. my form isn't like what you linked to...i have a html form...just html