# Pass contents of a list box to controller in Razor

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I'm very new at dealing with javascript. I have a listbox filled with IEnumerable values that I want to pass back to the controller but I'm stuck on how I would go about doing so. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this
[ASP.Net MVC How to pass data from view to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333021/asp-net-mvc-how-to-pass-data-from-view-to-controller)

or try use the Jquery ajax call this way. So I'm not sure what about lis tbox is.

Javascript

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

        var listbox = $('#yourListboxID');
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('Value', listbox[0].value);
        formData.append('ID', listbox[0].id);
        formData.append('OtherVariable',"..." );
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Ajax/Test', //url--> controller/Method
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json', // data type return form your controller
            data: formData, 
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result); //<--- "Sucess"
            },
            error: function (xhr, resp, text) {
                console.log(xhr, resp, text);
            }
        })

     });
```

AjaxController.cs

```
    [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
    public class AjaxController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Test(string value01)
        {    
            var ID = Request.Form["ID"].ToString();
            var Value = Request.Form["Value"].ToString(); 
            return Json("Sucess");
        }
    }
```