# POST controller action method is having a NULL ViewModel parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

My POST controller isn't able to capture the ViewModel parameter I set and I'm very confused as I have a different set of POST controller and it can capture the ViewModel parameter.

My code looks like this,

View Page

```
@model MyProject.Web.ViewModels.MyViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
    ViewBag.Description = "My Project";
    ViewBag.SubDescription = "My Project Tool";
    Layout = null;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Filter)
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-inline-right input-tab" value="Search" />
}
```

Controller

```
using MyProject.Web.ViewModels;

[HttpGet]
[Route("Home/Index")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    ...await API integration code here...

    return View(MyViewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("Home/Index/{viewmodel}")]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel viewmodel) <-- all properties of viewmodel are NULL
{
    return View();
}
```

View Model

```
using MyProject.Web.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyProject.Web.ViewModels
{
    public class MyViewModel 
    {
        public User UserInfo;
        public List<Client> Clients;

        public string Filter;
    }
}
```

I feel this is a very small mistake, maybe due to overlooking too much. Hopefully someone could take a look and help.

Comment: Show us your post request.

Comment: `"Home/Index/{viewmodel}"` seems a bit strange route since `viewmodel` is complex object

Comment: @Yan - I'm running it locally and the post isn't much. But the Form Data shows **Filter=testFilterValue**. Could you specify the specific part you would want to see?

Comment: @RistoM - what do you mean? Is it because of the List?

Comment: @Lex can you try giving a name to your input that maps to your view model property named filter like `<input name="filter"> </input> ` and see if you receive value in the filter property of your view model. and remove the route from the top of your post action

Comment: @ZeeshanAdil - seems working, so a good workaround.

Comment: good I guess the issue is with your route, can you go back to the old solution and just remove the route?

Comment: @RistoM - you might be correct. i tried to simplified it by using List of Client as the model in View instead of the complex view model. But still keen to figure out the correct solution on this. As having a view model that contains all necessary information is much more convenient - **_and clean_**.

Comment: @Lex have a look at my answer to understand what's happening.

Comment: @ZeeshanAdil Input tags are self-terminating, so `<input name="filter"> </input>` is never going to be valid.

Comment: @TiesonT. You are right, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the route you have defined on the top of your `Post` action `[Route("Home/Index/{viewmodel}")]`

You don't need that `{viewmodel}` in that URL as you are not posting anything in the query string, you are posting a complex object inside the body of your HTTP Post.

Remove that `route` and it should work.

also, ASP.NET mvc maps the inputs to the Model properties based upon the `name` attributes on them like `<input name="abc">` will map this input to a property named `abc` on a ViewModel or just a parameter. In your case `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Filter)` does that automatically.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

use this I hope useful:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "HomeController", FormMethod.Post))
```

Comment: Tried it but it doesn't work. The result is the same as before I'm afraid.

Comment: you can remove Route attribute, check this link I hope useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333021/asp-net-mvc-how-to-pass-data-from-view-to-controller

Answer (score 0):

Change from `public string Filter`  to property `public string Filter {get;set;}`

and change route to  `[Route("Home/Index")]` instead of `[Route("Home/Index/{viewmodel}")]`.

I tested and it worked.

```
public class MyViewModel
    {
        public User UserInfo { get; set; }
        public List<Client> Clients { get; set; }
        public string Filter { get; set; }
    }

[HttpPost]
[Route("Home/Index")]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel viewmodel)
{
    return View();
}
```