# How to pass data from viewmodel to?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to MVC and trying to understand viewmodels.
I have `Staff`, `Service`, `BookingSlot`, `Appointments` and the `ApplicationUser` entities. I have the following viewmodel:

```
public class AppointmentBookingViewModel
{
    [Display (Name ="Select Staff")]
    public int StaffId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Staff> Staffs { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Select Service")]
    public int ServiceId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Service> Services { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Select Slot")]
    public int BookingSlotId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<BookingSlot> BookingSlots { get; set; }

}
```

This is the controller:

```
public class AppointmentBookingController : Controller
{
    private readonly SalonContext _context;

    private AppointmentBookingViewModel _appointmentBookingViewModel = new AppointmentBookingViewModel();

    public AppointmentBookingController(SalonContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        ConfigureViewModel(_appointmentBookingViewModel);
    }

    public void ConfigureViewModel(AppointmentBookingViewModel appointmentBookingViewModel)
    {
        appointmentBookingViewModel.Staffs = _context.Staffs;
        appointmentBookingViewModel.Services = _context.Services;
        appointmentBookingViewModel.BookingSlots = _context.BookingSlots;
    }

    // GET: AppointmentBooking
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_appointmentBookingViewModel);
    }
}
```

My question is, how can I create a form in the view and post the data to the Appointments table, the following doesn't work.

```
@model HairStudio.Services.ViewModels.AppointmentBooking.AppointmentBookingViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ServiceId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="ServiceId" class="form-control"></select> 
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.Net MVC How to pass data from view to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333021/asp-net-mvc-how-to-pass-data-from-view-to-controller)

Comment: @zinov Altough there are a lot of similarities between ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Core MVC, they are still different frameworks, IMO making OP's question not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You already directed your form to action called *"Create"* with `asp-action` attribute, but there is no such action in your **controller**. Submitting a form sends a HTTP POST request, which needs to be handled by your controller. Therefore, add a `Create()` method in your `AppointmentBookingController`:

```cs
// POST: Create
public IActionResult Create(AppointmentBookingViewModel appointmentViewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Server side validation of form has failed.
        // Return to the calling view and inform the user about the errors.
        return View(appointmentViewModel, "Index");
    }

    return View(appointmentViewModel, "<NAME_OF_YOUR_CREATED_APPOINTMENT_VIEW>");
}
```

Consider redirecting after successfully accepting a HTTP POST request according to a design pattern [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Also, take a look at [this part](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms) of ASP.NET Core documentation about working with forms. I'm sure you'll find there something of value.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing magical about a view model. It's just a class. The idea is that the entity class (i.e. the thing you're persisting to the database via Entity Framework) should be concerned only with the needs of the database. A view can and often does have an entirely different set of needs, so you create a class specifically for that: the view model. This is just basic SRP (single-responsibility principle): a single class shouldn't try to do too much.

Then, you simply need a way to bridge the two. In other words, you need to copy values from the entity to the view model and vice versa. That process is called mapping, and can be achieved in a number of different ways. The most common approach is to use a third-party library like AutoMapper. However, you can also just manually map over each value or even use something akin to the factory pattern, where you have another class that holds the knowledge for how to do the mapping and can spit out an entity from a view model and vice versa.

Now, it's not really possible to give you exact guidance because we don't have your entity(ies), but you seem to be wanting to pick a particular `Staff`, `Service` and `BookingSlot` and associate that with the `Appointment` you're creating. It's not critical, but for efficiency, you should not be carrying around the full set of all these entities on your view model. All you need is an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, which allows you to use much more efficient queries:

Instead of the `Staffs` property, for example:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StaffOptions { get; set; }
```

Then:

```
model.StaffOptions = await _context.Staffs.AsNoTracking()
    .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.Id.ToString() })
    .ToListAsync();
```

In your view:

```
<select asp-for="StaffId" asp-items="@Model.StaffOptions" class="form-control"></select>
```