# How do I pass this parameter in my html code into an action in my controller

Tags: c#

[My HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3Btl.png)

How do i pass the #employee# from my html into an action in my controller ?

Comment: `?querystringparametername=value`

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="myController/myAction" method="POST">
 <input type="text" name="employee" />
 <input type="submit" value="View Report" />
</form> 
controller:

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult myAction(string  employee )
{
   //....
}
```

[ASP.Net MVC How to pass data from view to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333021/asp-net-mvc-how-to-pass-data-from-view-to-controller)